# Can there be two celery instances in a django application?

Tags: django, events, celery, microservices

I have a use case of using two celery instances in a same django application. One celery instance is used for incoming events to the app and the other is to publish an event to an external django application. Doing this is making connections to the celery workers timeout and blocking both the instances.

Comment: Could you use queues to differentiate between the tasks? Otherwise you could create separate celery app files and the celery worker process would specify which file to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  As @schillingt mentions, just have two separate app instances and start the workers using the appropriate value for the `-A` flag.